# Using just javascript how do you select a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet using javascript to mark a checkbox that corresponds to aria-labelledby=:picasa-checkbox-280-label". The webpage was not letting me use jquery code and I could not use a jquerify bookmarklet on the page to write the code in jquery.

The ultimate goal is to have an input of multiple different #-labels and have all their checkboxes get checked

```
<picasa-table-cell max-width="50px" class="picasa-table__cell hydrated" role="cell" style="width: 1%; min-width: 1.4286rem; max-width: 50px; text-align: left;">
<!---->
    <picasa-checkbox role="checkbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" aria-labelledby="picasa-checkbox-280-label" class="hydrated">
        #shadow-root (open)
            <label id="picasa-checkbox-280-label" class="picasa-checkbox">
                <div class="picasa-checkbox__container">
                    <input class="picasa-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="" value="">
                    <span class="picasa-checkbox__checkmark"></span>
                    </div>
                    <slot></slot></label>
        
        </picasa-checkbox>
</picasa-table-cell>
```

My current line of thinking is to use the click() function to select the checkbox but that is giving me an error

'''
javascript: (function() {
document.querySelector('.element[aria-labelledby="picasa-checkbox-280-label"]')[0].click();
})();
'''

But it is giving me an error of
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')`

Comment: you forget shadowRoot the query look like this : document.querySelector('picasa-checkbox[aria-labelledby="picasa-checkbox-280-label"']).shadowRoot.querySelector('label[id="picasa-checkbox-280-label"]').click()

Comment: Remember to use properly querySelector that returns a single element and querySelectorAll that returns all the matches

Answer (score 1):

You forget shadowRoot because Element.querySelector() doesn't offer a shortcut for traversing shadow roots so we have to do this

```
document.querySelector('form').shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
```

Demo to check a checkbox under a shadowRoot :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  //Adding the shadow element
  
  document.querySelector('picasa-checkbox[aria-labelledby="picasa-checkbox-280-label"]').attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = '<label id="picasa-checkbox-280-label" class="picasa-checkbox"><div class="picasa-checkbox__container"><input class="picasa-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> <span class="picasa-checkbox__checkmark"></span></div><slot></slot></label>';


  //Click checkbox

  document.querySelector('picasa-checkbox[aria-labelledby="picasa-checkbox-280-label"]').shadowRoot.querySelector('label[id="picasa-checkbox-280-label"]').click();

});
```

```html
<picasa-table-cell max-width="50px" class="picasa-table__cell hydrated" role="cell" style="width: 1%; min-width: 1.4286rem; max-width: 50px; text-align: left;"><picasa-checkbox role="checkbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" aria-labelledby="picasa-checkbox-280-label" class="hydrated">
</picasa-checkbox></picasa-table-cell>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am a total amateur at this and my knowledge is like swiss cheese with little cheese, just needing to know enough to save my wrists from carpal tunnel. The one problem I had was that the code snippet I originally gave was in a shadow-root and had to add that part to the code but it works now. Thanks so much.